# Translate cross_validation algorithm to model_selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas

In 2016, I ran a lasso regression model using the code below:

```
#Import required packages 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plp
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoLarsCV

# split data into train and test sets
pred_train, pred_test, tar_train, tar_test = train_test_split(predictors, target, test_size=.4, random_state=123)
#%
# specify the lasso regression model
model=LassoLarsCV(cv=10, precompute=False).fit(pred_train,tar_train)
#%
# print variable names and regression coefficients
dict(zip(predictors.columns, model.coef_))
#regcoef.to_csv('variable+regresscoef.csv')
#%%
# plot coefficient progression
m_log_alphas = -np.log10(model.alphas_)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(m_log_alphas, model.coef_path_.T)
plt.axvline(-np.log10(model.alpha_), linestyle='--', color='k',
            label='alpha CV')
plt.ylabel('Regression Coefficients')
plt.xlabel('-log(alpha)')
plt.title('Regression Coefficients Progression for Lasso Paths')
#%
# plot mean square error for each fold
m_log_alphascv = -np.log10(model.cv_alphas_)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(m_log_alphascv, model.cv_mse_path_, ':')
plt.plot(m_log_alphascv, model.cv_mse_path_.mean(axis=-1), 'k',
         label='Average across the folds', linewidth=2)
plt.axvline(-np.log10(model.alpha_), linestyle='--', color='k',
            label='alpha CV')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('-log(alpha)')
plt.ylabel('Mean squared error')
plt.title('Mean squared error on each fold')
#%       
# MSE from training and test data
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
train_error = mean_squared_error(tar_train, model.predict(pred_train))
test_error = mean_squared_error(tar_test, model.predict(pred_test))
print ('training data MSE')
print(train_error)
print ('test data MSE')
print(test_error)
#%
# R-square from training and test data
rsquared_train=model.score(pred_train,tar_train)
rsquared_test=model.score(pred_test,tar_test)
print ('training data R-square')
print(rsquared_train)
print ('test data R-square')
print(rsquared_test)
```

Now I want to run it again and got the following warning:

> DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in
>   favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored
>   classes and functions are moved.

How can I rewrite this code using `model_selection` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I can see here that used `cross_validation` module earlier is `train_test_split`.

So just change your import from:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

to:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

and you are good to go.